# React.js app using up a lot of memory ( almost double the original implementation )

Tags: javascript, memory, google-chrome-devtools, reactjs

I recently ported a heavy page to React. I've kept the html almost identical. The main difference being that, earlier, the server rendered html was directly given to the browser and now, the react rewrite pulls json via a  server side API and uses React to manage the DOM.

I've seen heap snapshots for the earlier implementation going up to **55 MBs**. For the same data, the heap snapshot for the React.js implementation comes to around **100+ MBs**(almost double)

[image: Chrome dev tools heap snapshot screenshot]

I understand that the json data held in memory will contribute to some increase in the memory consumed. But, when I examined the heap snapshot, I see that around 60% of the retained size is due to some objects whose retaining path contain **deleteAllListeners > .... > unmountComponentAtNode** . I am trying to understand what that means in terms of reducing the memory used.

Also, could the **"data-reactid"** attributes added by React to the DOM contribute to a non-negligible  increase in memory consumption ?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435915/getinitialstate-cloneprops) has some more details that might help.

Comment: It's not clear how to try to answer your question without more details. `data-reactid` is non-negligible, but I wouldn't expect it to contribute a significant amount in a typical page. You can see [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=deleteAllListeners+) how the `deleteAllListeners` is used. Do you have a lot of event listeners maybe?

Comment: Could http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435915/getinitialstate-cloneprops contribute to the increased memory usage as the state is cloned from props(which is then never used again ) ?

Comment: How much data is being cloned? If you do the multiplication to account for the copies, what's the result?

Answer (score 10):

React is using something called Virtual DOM. Basically it constructs alternative DOM tree in memory, in addition to the existing browser DOM tree, but to perform efficient updates it has to keep last displayed Virtual DOM tree in memory, so it can generate fast and efficient updates to the browser DOM tree.

From details of second question, I understand that you have an infinite scroll, where you basically add new components (without removing new ones) when user scrolls down the page. So this should be the source of increased memory usage (since now you have data + virtual dom in memory, compared to the previous solution)

The way it fix it is to render only components which are actually visible to the user, you can try to use [react-list](https://github.com/orgsync/react-list), or implement your own component for this.